# Shortcut to open file in Vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to open a file in Vim like in Eclipse using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, or via the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> option of autofill. Invoke a keyboard shortcut, type the file name/pattern, and choose from all the matching files names.

I know opening it normally like:

```
:tabe <filepath>
:new <filepath>
:edit <filepath>
```

The problem here is that I have to specify the whole file path in these cases.

Comment: Note that the suggested commands have different effect `:tabe` will open the file in a new tab, `:new` will horizontally split the window, and `:edit` will close the current file before opening the new one.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I recently fell in love with [fuzzyfinder.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984)
... :-)

*:FuzzyFinderFile* will let you open files by typing partial names or patterns.

Answer (score 147):

What I normally do is `e .` (e-space-dot) which gives me a browsable current directory - then I can `/` - search for name fragments, just like finding a word in a text file. I find that generally good enough, simple and quick.

Comment: You don't need the space, saving an additional 25% typing. (`:e.`).

Comment: You don't need the dot if you use a capital e, e.g.  :E<ENTER>

Comment: @drozzy This happens with vim :-)

Comment: There is a difference in the behaviour between `:e.` and `:E` though : if the current file has been edited and not saved yet, the former will complain (like `:edit`) because of "no write since last change", while the latter will horizontally split the window (like `:new`) to allow the opening of a new file (while both will replace the current file with the new file if it hasn't been modified (like `:edit`)).

Comment: How does one exit from this view if they want to continue editing the file they are already editing without closing vim entirely?

Comment: If you open a file, then replace it with a second file, you can get back to the first using "e #"

Answer (score 36):

`:find` is another option.

I open vim from the root of my project and have the `path` set to there.

Then, I can open files located anywhere in the tree using:

```
:find **/filena< tab >
```

Tab will autocomplete through various matches. (`**` tells it to search recursively through the path).

Comment: I don't find useful `:find` since to get the path relative to the working directory. See the question and @romainl answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224168/vim-using-find-how-to-get-the-path-relative-to-the-working-directory/28225117#28225117 . I find more interesting @strager answer to get the path relative to the working directory easier.

Answer (score 26):

You can search for a file in the current path by using `**`:

```
:tabe **/header.h
```

Hit tab to see various completions if there is more than one match.

Comment: I tried using this but this is like so slow. I mean my application is big and the editor stopped working for sometime. Do you know any setting to increase the editor performance and speed.

Comment: Nice answer. Use something like `:tabe **/*der.h` if you don't remember the full name of the file.

Answer (score 16):

Consider using [CtrlP](http://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) plug-in.

It is included in [Janus Distributive](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus).

Allows you to find files in the current directory, open buffers or most recently used files using "fuzzy matching" or regular expression.

Comment: actually I use it as a part of Janus distribution.

Comment: The original CtrlP repo is inactive, but there is an [active fork](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim)

Answer (score 14):

unless I'm missing something, :e filename is the fastest way I've found.

You can use tab to autocomplete the filename as well.

Comment: @dirkgently, It is.  It's still a shortcut, as the title of this question suggests, but I don't think it's what the questioner is looking for.

Comment: For me tab autocomplete does not work for :e. Besides you don't always want to search for filename that starts with something, but rather for a middle word in a filename.

Answer (score 11):

I like the :FuzzyFinderTextMate (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) on my setup.
See http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2008/10/10/coming-home-to-vim

Answer (score 9):

I use a couple of shortcuts in my .vimrc file (exact syntax below).

They are based on the fact that in 90% of the cases, I want to open another file in the same directory as the file that I am currently editing, or in a directory that is very close in the hierarchy to that edited file.

**Here's what the commands do do:**

`,cd` : Change the current working directory to the directory that the current file you are editing is in.

`,e` : Opens a file with the current working directory already filled in so you have to specify **only** the filename.

**Put these into your .vimrc:**

```
map ,e :e <C-R>=expand("%:p:h") . "/" <CR>

map ,cd :cd %:p:h <CR>
```

**Here's a sequence of events:**

---

1. You are editing a file called test.java in "/home/prog"
2. `,cd` -> Current working directory now
   becomes "/home/prog"
3. `,e` -> Expands to ":e /home/prog" so
   that you can just fill in the file
   name, say test.h.

---

1. `,e` -> Expands to ":e /home"
2. `tab` -> Cycle through subdirectories of /home
3. `enter` -> `cd` to the directory you
   want say /home/prog
4. `,e` -> Expands to ":e /home/prog"

Answer (score 8):

There's also command-t which I find to be the best of the bunch (and I've tried them all).  It's a minor hassle to install it but, once it's installed, it's a dream to use.

https://wincent.com/products/command-t/

Comment: You might want to try ctrlp.vim (https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) as well. It's basically the same as Command-T but written in pure Vimscript. (IMHO it is simpler to use as well)

Answer (score 6):

Use tabs, they work when inputting file paths in vim escape mode!

Answer (score 4):

If you've got tags (and you should), you can open a file from the command line just by the name of the class or method or c function, with "vim -t DBPlaylist", and within vim with ":tag ShowList".

Answer (score 4):

If you're editing files in a common directory, you can `:cd` to that directory, then use `:e` on just the filename.

For example, rather than:

```
:e /big/long/path/that/takes/a/while/to/type/or/tab/complete/thingy.rb
:sp /big/long/path/that/takes/a/while/to/type/or/tab/complete/other_thingy.c
:vs /big/long/path/that/takes/a/while/to/type/or/tab/complete/one_more_thingy.java
```

You can do:

```
:cd /big/long/path/that/takes/a/while/to/type/or/tab/complete/
:e thingy.rb
:sp other_thingy.c
:vs one_more_thingy.java
```

Or, if you already have a file in the desired directory open, you can use the `%` shorthand for the current filename, and trim it to the current directory with the `:h` modifier (`:help :_%:`) :

```
:e /big/long/path/that/takes/a/while/to/type/or/tab/complete/thingy.rb
:cd %:h
:sp other_thingy.c
:vs one_more_thingy.java
```

And, like others have said, you can tab-complete file names on the ex-line (see `:help cmdline-completion` for more).

Answer (score 4):

This isn't *exactly* what you're looking for, but it's good in many cases (though not all).

If you VIM open and there's a name of a file in the buffer, you can put the cursor on that filename and type <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>.  This opens the file whose name is under the cursor in the same buffer.  It's the same as

`:e CTRL+r CTRL+w`

Comment: I pressed gf and now I have opened the new file which is under the curssor. Now how to come back to the original file.!!

Comment: @user430294: It's open in a different buffer. Use `:b oldname`

Comment: @vrbilgi, use Ctrl+o to go back to the previously edited file. Use Ctrl+i to go forward again to the file from which you are back.

Answer (score 3):

I know three plugins that permit to open files, support auto-completion, and don't require to enter the full path name of the file(s) to open (as long as the files are under one of the directories from `&path` vim option):

- [searchInRuntime](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/searchInRuntime) that I'm maintaining (the completion is not on `:e`/`:find`, but on split actions)
- [fuzzy finder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) as it has been already pointed out,
- [lookupfile](http://www.vim.org//scripts/script.php?script_id=1581).

Lately, I've seen another plugin with a similar feature, but I don't remember the name.

Soon, :find is likely support auto-completion -- patches on this topic are circulating on vim_dev mailing-list these days.

Answer (score 1):

- you can use (set wildmenu)
- you can use tab to autocomplete filenames
- you can also use matching, for example :e `p*.dat` or something like that (like in old' dos)
- you could also :browse confirm e (for a graphical window)
- but you should also probably specify what vim version you're using, and how that thing in emacs works. Maybe we could find you an exact vim alternative.

Answer (score 1):

FuzzyFinder has been mentioned, however I love the textmate like behaviour of the [FuzzyFinderTextmate](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2008/11/17/vim-follow-up) plugin which extends the behaviour to include all subdirs.

Make sure you are using version 2.16 of fuzzyfinder.vim - The higher versions break the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

With Exuberant ctags, you can create tag files with file information:

```
ctags --extra=+f -R *
```

Then, open file from VIM with

```
:tag filename
```

You can also use `<tab>` to autocomplete file name.

Answer (score 1):

In GVIM, The file can be browsed using open / read / write dialog;

```
:browse {command}
```

{command} - open / read / write

**open** - Opens the file
**read** - Appends the file
**write** - SaveAs dialog

Answer (score 0):

I installed FuzzyFinder. However, the limitation is that it only finds files in the current dir. One workaround to that is to add FuzzyFinderTextmate. However, based on the docs and commentary, that doesn't work reliably. You need the right version of FuzzyFinder and you need your copy of Vim to be compiled with Ruby support.

A different workaround I'm trying out now is to open all the files I'm likely to need at the beginning of the editing session. E.g., open all the files in key directories...

```
:args app/**
:args config/**
:args test/**
etc...
```

(This means I would have possibly scores of files open, however so far it still seems to work OK.)

After that, I can use FuzzyFinder in buffer mode and it will act somewhat like TextMate's `command-o` shortcut...

```
:FuzzyFinderBuffer
```

Comment: You sure? I have some config in my .vimrc, look for "g:fuf_abbrevMap". I must have found an example in the documentation. When I type the shortcut, I then type an abbrev like "web:" and it will lookup all files within a folder of my choice. My problem actually is that for some reason it doesn't open files anymore, I see [NEW DIRECTORY] in the status bar instead. But I have the same problem with :o, seems unrelated to fuf.