# vim: using "find", how to get the path relative to the working directory

Tags: vim

how can I get the path relative to the working directory of the file using `find`? now I just get a part of the path..

I mean, when I write `find **/*Confirm` and press Tab I get this:

```
:find UserArea/activacionGarantiaConfirm.html.twig
```

but I expected the path relative to my working directory:

```
:find Project/views/UserArea/activacionGarantiaConfirm.html.twig
```

Comment: `:find` is relative to your current working directory. Do `:pwd` to print your current working directory. Do you want it relative to something else?

Comment: @PeterRincker after `:pwd` I get `/home/tirengarfio/workspace/procom/src`. After `src` comes `Project/views...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `:find`'s completion doesn't print any part of the path of potential files beyond the file name. Adding a "starstar" wildcard forces it to print the parent directory and another "starstar" will print another parent and so on…

If seeing the full path of every file is important to you, you should use `:edit` which prints the complete path, relative to the current directory by default.